# Django Detailview Error Handling

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a scenario where I am trying to send different messages to the user in the event that they are not authorized to see a record or if the record does not exist.  I have been able to get the interface to send a message to the user if a 404 occurs, but can't quite figure out the logic based on criteria of the record.  I've been playing with get, get_object, or get_object_or_404 and nothing quite works.

Here is my DetailView..

```
class BookSearchDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):

    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_detail'
    template_name = 'book/book_search_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Book, book_number=self.request.GET.get("q"))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book_number=self.request.GET.get("q")
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Book Number %s Not Found' % book_number )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Book:book_number_search'))
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
        except Not a Preference:
            Book_number exists but is not self.request.user.preferences.all()
```

I realize the except Not a Preference doesn't work, but I am illustrating what I am trying to do.

Here is my model.

```
class Book(models.Model):

    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,unique=False)
    book_number = models.IntegerField(editable=True,null=True)
```

Note I do not have a  slug defined to my model.  In the current code above, this doesn't cause any problems.  When I have played with different code variations, one of the error messages I get is that DetailView must be called with a pk or a slug.

I am ultimately trying to filter the book so that if the user doesn't have attributes to allow them to see the book it would essentially return none.

I have also tried to override get_queryset, but when I use the code below,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(BookSearchDetailView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(book_number__in=self.request.user.preferences.all())
```

However, when I define the code above, my DetailView does not seem to honor it or have any effect.

What I've read is that the get_object either gets the object or 404.  I've got that piece work working fine.  Just can't figure out how to incorporate a third variation of error message.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: can you explain  this line `incorporate a third variation of error message`?

Comment: Sure....I'll update my example above.